# Twitter returns UserJSONImpl instead of Twitter User object

Tags: android, twitter4j

When i am trying to get Twitter User from Twitter it returns me UserJsonImpl
i am not able to understand it. How to handle this return Json from twitter. it must return me Twitter User object as its function described.

```
User user =twitter.showUser(TwitterUserID);
```

Here in this line i get UserJsonImpl

Comment: User is an interface, so it's natural that you get an implementation of this interface. What does "I am not able to understand it" mean in this context?

Comment: @Egor How do i get User object from it.

Comment: It IS a User object, it is an instance of class UserJsonImpl which implements User interface.

Comment: @Egor can u share some code so i understand